# How to prevent combobox SelectionChanged event on binding time (WPf)?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf application combo box SelectionChanged event firing on binding time, how to fix it?

```
<telerik:RadComboBox 
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    OpenDropDownOnFocus="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SiteSurveyModel.AtsNumberCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    IsFilteringEnabled="False"
    IsEditable="False">
    <ie:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ie:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <ie:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ATSRadComboBoxSelectedItemChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=atsRadComboBox}" >
            </ie:InvokeCommandAction>
        </ie:EventTrigger>
    </ie:Interaction.Triggers>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

And

```
private void BindAtsNumberCollection()
{
    try
    {
        List<int> NumberList = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            NumberList.Add(i);
        }
        SiteSurveyModel.AtsNumberCollection = new ObservableCollectionEx<int>(NumberList);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      customerAC.LogFile(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

And Selection change method is as

```
private void onATSRadComboBoxSelectedItemChangedCommand(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        RadComboBox atsRadComboBox = obj as RadComboBox;
         string  selectedValue= atsRadComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
         if (selectedValue.Trim() != string.Empty)
         {
             BindAtsData(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
         }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        customerAC.LogFile(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

> We are performing some calculation and when it's firing on loading time then result will be come wrong and we are very frustrate  how to fix this. Please provide need full solution.

Comment: Well it IS changing, so preventing the change event sounds like you want to hide an issue that originates from a different part.

Comment: Hi grek40, are you understand my issue? when page is opening then event is firing, I do not want like this . Any solution?

Comment: Is the event firing without an actual change to the selection or is the selection changed on binding time? Thats two completely different things and in the end you may have to update your handler code, because it's probably not possible to block the event from firing without deriving your own custom control. Or if it is possible, consider the possibility of other components relying on the event to be fired. You are not guaranteed to be the only listener.

Comment: "Is the event firing without an actual change to the selection"  Yes. You want to see the code of selection change  event?

Comment: If you want suggestions on how to change the code then I probably have to see it. However, it shouldn't be to hard, just to inspect the `SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems` and `SelectionChangedEventArgs.RemovedItems` collections and return from the handler if both are empty.

Comment: hi grek40, code added with comment, Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't use `SelectedValuePath` I'd suggest to use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`.

Anyway, if no item is selected, I'd expect `SelectedValue` to be `null`, which should screw at line `atsRadComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()`. So what you need is a way to handle "de-select" or at least a simple `null` check which cancels the handler instead of trying `ToString` and binding.

```
private void onATSRadComboBoxSelectedItemChangedCommand(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        RadComboBox atsRadComboBox = obj as RadComboBox;
        if (atsRadComboBox.SelectedValue == null) return;
        string  selectedValue= atsRadComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (selectedValue.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
            BindAtsData(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        customerAC.LogFile(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you are interested in a minimal change, this should already do the trick.

More generally, it looks like you could introduce a viewmodel property

```
private int? _selectedNumber
public int? SelectedNumber
{
    get { return _selectedNumber; }
    set
    {
        _selectedNumber = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedNumber");
        if (_selectedNumber.HasValue) BindAtsData(_selectedNumber.Value);
        else { /* some kind of de-select needed? */ }
    }
}
```

By binding this property directly to the `RadComboBox.SelectedItem`, there would be no need for the whole `Interaction` - `EventTrigger` workaround. Also, to be honest I don't understand why the `SiteSurveyModel.AtsNumberCollection` would be two-way. Consider making it one-way instead.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
    Name="atsRadComboBox"
    Width="150" Height="30" MaxHeight="30" MinHeight="30"
    Margin="5,0,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
    OpenDropDownOnFocus="True"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SiteSurveyModel.AtsNumberCollection}"
    SelectedItem={Binding SelectedNumber,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
    IsFilteringEnabled="False"
    IsEditable="False"
    IsTextSearchCaseSensitive="False"
    TextSearchMode="Contains"/>
```

As a side note: how about replacing

```
List<int> NumberList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    NumberList.Add(i);
}
SiteSurveyModel.AtsNumberCollection = new ObservableCollectionEx<int>(NumberList);
```

with

```
SiteSurveyModel.AtsNumberCollection = new ObservableCollectionEx<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 100));
// or if you absolutely need a `List<int>`
SiteSurveyModel.AtsNumberCollection = new ObservableCollectionEx<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList());
```

It's a bit less code.

Comment: You are right  that I can return but when then we getting null, In my case we are getting '1' as selected value, Please provide more relevant solution.

Comment: @MatthewSiddle Please provide more relevant information, then I can have another look at it. But I don't know what you mean with *"when then we getting null we getting 1 as selected value"*

Comment: I am saying that 'we are getting 1 as selected value instead of null on the binding time'. So this approach is wrong in my case.                                   if (atsRadComboBox.SelectedValue == null) return;

Comment: @MatthewSiddle stop it right there! As I previously asked: "Is the event firing without an actual change to the selection" and you answered: "Yes". Now you come and tell me that the `SelectedValue` is `1` so clearly, there was an actual change in the selected item. Get your facts together, use tools like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). Stackoverflow is not a debugging site nor a professional site to fix your problems. If you ask the wrong question, you get unfitting answers, thats all there ever was to this story.

Comment: @MatthewSiddle Still I have another idea: set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"` instead of `True` unless you actually interact with the `CollectionView.CurrentItem`. This is most likely the cause for having an initial selected item after binding.

Comment: I want to know that why this is occurring at time of page initialization or binding time. thanks for the suggest. We will remember this.
Ok, But i want to show default selected value then how to manage this?

Comment: Your question was about preventing / handling `SelectionChanged` event. If you want to define an initially selected item, you can look around if you find a solution and then maybe ask a separate question. If you follow the approach from my answer with `SelectedNumber`, it should be trivial to set an initial value.

Comment: thanks, For help, I got a solution from you suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Checking below condition worked for me,

e.RemovedItems.Count == 0

This count is 0 when loading the binding.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve preventing fire `ComboBox.SelectionChanged`, Inside the `SelectionChanged` event, use `Row.RowState=DataRowState.Modified` to know if you have to do things or not.